# Rails: Concat Two CollectionProxies with two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

As the title explains, say I have two ActiveRecord::Base models: SatStudentAnswer and ActStudentAnswer.

I have a Student model

```
has_many :act_student_answers
has_many :sat_student_answers
```

I would like to create a collection proxy that concats them together so I can query all student answers together.

```
student.sat_student_answers.concat(student.act_student_answers)
```

However I get an 
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: SatStudentAnswer(#70111600189260) expected, got ActStudentAnswer(#70111589566060)` error.

Is there a way to create a collection proxy with two different models so I can continue using the Active Record query interface? If not, what would be the best way to solve this problem?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't way to create Rails AR:Relation with different models in it (I digged in this issue when I needed to create newsfeed with different kind of posts). My solution wasn't very beautiful, but was working: I've created additional model with polymorphic **has_many**. You could query collection of these new defined models and distinguish sat_answers and act_answers by field answer_type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
array = student.sat_student_answers + student.act_student_answers
```

Then for example

```
array.each {|item| p item.student}
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. As stated in the question, I still want it to be a CollectionProxy (not a ruby array) so I can use the Active Record query interface.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you actually want the two models to be just one model categorized into two things `act` and `sat`.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :answers
  # ...
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  scope :act, -> { where kind: :act }
  scope :sat, -> { where kind: :sat }
  # ...
end
```

Then you'll be able to do your `concat`.

```
student.answers.act.concat student.answers.sat
# that is similar to
student.answers.act << student.answers.sat
```

However, `concat` methods adds the records to the receiving association and saves it in the DB if the owner of the association is persisted. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do there. Are you mixing the ACT answers with SAT answers making SAT answers include the ACT answers?

See: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/concat

What you probably want is below:

```
student.answers
# or
act_and_sat_answers = student.answers.where(kind: [:act, :sat])

# chain more filter query
act_and_sat_answers.where(correct: true)
```

If you really want to use two distinct models then you'll have to create your own collection proxy.